# sum of all prime numbers between 100 and 200

Tags: java, int, boolean, primes

I'm actually about to loose my mind... The code I wrote displays every kind of "sum" and "count" between the actual last result I want to display with `System.out.print(...)`. Can someone help me please? What did I do wrong for it to display everything?

```
public class Prim {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int end = 11;
        int count = 1;
        long sum = 0;

        for (int number = 10; count<=end; number++) {
            if (isPrim(number)) { 
               sum = sum + number;
               count++; 
               System.out.println(sum);
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean isPrim(int number){
        for (int i=2; i<number; i++) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
            }
        }
        return true; 
    }
}
```

Comment: The code does not compile

Comment: How about return false in  isPrime sometimes?

Comment: Right now, this code won't compile. Also `isPrim` does nothing at all.

Comment: First, there is a conflict between `istPrimzahl()` and `isPrim()` which aren't the same. Then, your `isPrim()` method should return false if it finds some null remainder to the division.

Comment: And `zahl` is not the same as `number`. There is also nothing in your code that checks whether the number is between 100 and 200. And it's totally unclear what you're asking - what is it that is wrong with the code, what did you expect and what is actually happening (the method and variable name errors are presumably due to a sloppy attempt at translating your code into English)

Comment: Im sorry! I edited the code again, should compile now.

Answer (score 1):

A few things.

First, your `isPrim` can be optimised so that `i` only increments until `sqrt(number)`.

Second, you need to `return false` if `(number%i == 0)` is `true`. Right now, it's always returning `true`, which is why your code is outputting all sums.

Third, you need to change `istPrimeZahl` to `isPrim` (or vice versa), as you haven't defined `istPrimeZahl` anywhere.

Fourth, you can change `sum = sum + number` to simply `sum += number`.

Finally, you probably want to move your `System.out.print` line two lines below, so that it only prints the `sum` *after* the loop has ended, not at every iteration of the loop.

(Also, you might want to change your `for` loop so that it starts at *100*, not 10  :)  )

If you want the final version, I've pasted it here:

```
public class Prim {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int end = 200;
        int count = 0;
        long sum = 0;

        for (int number = 100; number<=end; number++) {
            if (isPrim(number)) { 
               sum += number;
               count++; 
               System.out.println(sum);
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean isPrim(int number){
        for (int i=2; i*i<=number; i++) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should you use counter and end parameters?

Comment: and you should i*i<=number not only <

Comment: @idan Edited the `<=` bit ... the OP probably needs `count` to know how many primes there were, and `end` is better as it means that the value isn't hardcoded into the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

The isPrim function is missing a 'return false' after the if statement. This means that isPrim will always return true, and consequently every number will get written to the console.

The System.out.print is also within for-loop, so it will print an updated sum each time. It's unclear if this is intentional, but if you want to only get a single result then that should also be moved two lines lower.

Answer (score 0):

For sum of prime numbers between 100 to 200, try this code:

```
public class Primzahlen {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 100; i < 200; i++)
            if (isPrim(i))
                sum += i;
        System.out.print(sum);
    }

    public static boolean isPrim(int num) {
        for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i++)
            if (num % i == 0)
                return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```